# QlikSense intermediary tables with geomap: What is a Line Layer expecting in "data?"

Tags: sql, qliksense

I wish to create a line layer that draws a line between points A and B, given a latitude and longitude value. Some point As have multiple point Bs, and vise versa.

---

### My Structure

Within a table, I will be calling the rows data "entries", and the columns data "fields."

There are three tables. Animals_Table, and Zoos_Table have information on specific things, while Foo_Table is an intermediary table used to associate the two to what relationships need to be.

**Example of Animals_Table:**

[image: animals table example pic]

**Example of Zoos_Table:**

[image: zoos table example pic]

**Example of Foo_Table:**

[image: intermediary table example pic]

**QlikSense Data Associations:**

- Animals_Table.ID to Foo_Table.AnimalsID
- Zooz_Table.ID to Foo_Table.ZoosID

---

### The Problem

I'm having some trouble understanding the [QlikSense documentation](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/geoanalytics/Subsystems/GeoPropertiesS/Content/qliksense/qliksense-imap_reference-Line-Layer.htm), because it does not specifically say what an expected value of the "Data" field is when editing the QlikSense sheet.

If I'm providing the location with long and lat with both the start and end point, **then what is QlikSense expecting the "Data" field to be?**

**Can I completely disable this field, and strictly tell it to use the lat/long values I'm giving it in the "Locations" tab?**

### What I've Tried

At this point I'm going in circles, and am repeating the following things:

• Putting every combination of fields from Animals_Table (in starting point) to Zoos_Table (in ending point) into the "Data" tab with Start point lat/long locations enabled, trying `Lat` and `Animals.Lat` for Latitude and `Long` and `Animals.Long`  for Longitude. Same thing for end point, but with Table_Zoos.

• Putting the Foo_Table intermediary table in "Data", using `Animals.ID` for the starting point and `Zoos.ID` for the ending point.

• Putting the Foo_table intermediary table in "Data", trying random combinations of extensions to the entries' ID, such as `AnimalsID.ID.Name` or `ZoosID.Longitude` to try and get anything.

Comment: I haven't forgotten about this question -it's still unanswered